# PhoneGap Android - Android Project From Existing Code Results in the following project name __PACKAGE__.__ACTIVITY__

Tags: android, cordova

After going through the PhoneGap Android tutorial, I finally got the the "create" command to work.  Now when I add the project to Eclipse via the "Android Project from existing code" wizard, it doesn't have the correct project name or package name.

**PACKAGE**._*ACTIVITY*_

But I used the following create command, so the project name should not be that.

C:\Users\kyle.jones\Downloads\cordova-2.4.0-src\cordova-2.4.0\cordova-android\bin>create C:\Users\kyle.jones\Downloads\cordova-2.4.0-src\cordova-2.4.0\cordova-android\kyle\adcraffle com.25k.adcraffle adcraffle

EDIT -
I realized there is an error buried in the console output when I ran the create command.  I am going to look into this error and delete this question if that is the culprit.

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
Creating new android project...
Building jar and js files...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Creating appinfo.jar...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
C:\Users\kyle.jones\Downloads\cordova-2.4.0-src\cordova-2.4.0\cordova-android\bi
n\create.js(31, 5) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Path not found
```

Comment: So the solution is to create the android project in the Cordova bin folder, otherwise the "create" command doesn't work properly.